# AKS Ingress Routing Issue With Multiple Hosts

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have an Ingress Controller file in my Kubernetes cluster that looks like such:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my_ingress_service_name
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 70m 
spec:  
  rules:
    - host: some.host.com 
      http:
        paths: 
          - path: /api/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: gateway
                port:
                  number: 4156
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: testpartner
                port:
                  number: 8090
    - host: someother.host.com 
      http:
        paths: 
          - path: /api/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: gateway
                port:
                  number: 4156
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: testpartner
                port:
                  number: 8090
```

When I navigate to any of the hosts (I have this hosted in Azure Kubernetes, with IP Addesses and an A record pointing to my kubernetes cluster) I can successfully see my web application. However, when I try to go to the api route such as

```
some.host.com/api/someApiController

or

someother.host.com/api/someApiController
```

I get a 404 not found error. Here is what is returned in the logs:

```
10.240.0.4 - - [13/Jul/2022:10:22:51 +0000] "GET /api/request/partner HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4" 401 0.002 [ingress-basic-gateway-4156] [] 10.240.0.65:4156 0 0.004 404 7a315bb0a56147e39ef692000dc0adfb
```

To be clear, it is on purpose that my application can have different hosts pointing to the same Kubernetes service with the same pods, so the different hosts will go the same container, but their APIs will also be a different container, so two containers total.

If it is helpful, here is the nginx config file for the web container (testpartner)

```
server {

  listen 8090;

  sendfile on;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  client_max_body_size 50M;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   1100;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;


  root /usr/share/nginx/html;


  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have also verified that the gateway is in fact listening to the correct port.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the API pod via `kubectl port-forward`, just to make sure it really works (doesn't return a 404)?

Comment: How would you go about doing that? Sorry not well versed in Kubernetes

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/